# Javascript promises - retrieve result

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to retrieve the result of a series of promises below and store it into a variable, so that I could use it outside of this chain. That being said, I keep on getting errors or the variable comes out as undefined.

Here's the series:

I've tried storing the promises in a variable i.e. var customerToken = //the code below. But, customerToken comes out as undefined, since the promises end after the variable is set.

```
var Stripe = StripeAPI('sk_test_key');

Stripe.customers.create({
  email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
  description: "SIDIM 2016",
  source: stripeToken
}).then(function(customer) {

  return Stripe.tokens.create({
    customer: customer.id
  }, {stripe_account: "acct_XXXYYYZZZ"});

}).then(function(token) {

  console.log(token);

  var charge = Stripe.customers.create({
    email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
    description: "SIDIM 2016",
    source: token.id
  }, {stripe_account: "acct_XXXYYYZZZ"});

  console.log(charge);

}).then(function(charge) {

  return Stripe.charges.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: charge.id
  }, {stripe_account: "acct_XXXYYYZZZ"});

}).catch(function(err) {
  // Deal with an error
});
```

Comment: Which variable are you trying to store? No value is returned from second `.then()`

Comment: I would like to store the customer.id in the first return and the charge.id in the last one. The second one doesn't have a return because of my sad attempt to store the result in a variable.

Comment: Do you want to store the `customer.id` outside of `Stripe.tokens.create({` call? Or, after the return value from `Stripe.tokens.create({` ?

Comment: I would like to store it outside of the entire thing, so that I can insert it into the DB in a separate function and use it later on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Comment: @NimaAmin take a look at Bergi's Mutable contextual state answer to the above question

Answer (score 0):

You can `return` the values from each `.then()`, access values at `.then()` after chain

```js
var customerTokens = Promise.resolve()
.then(function() {
    // do stuff
    var customerId = 1;
    return customerId; // return `customerId` here
})
.then(function(id) {
    // do stuff
    return id // return `id` : `customerId` here
})
.then(function(id) {
    // do stuff
    var chargeId = 2;
    return [id, chargeId]; // return both `customerId`:`id` and `chargeId`
})
.catch(function(err) {

});

customerTokens
.then(function(ids) {
    console.log(ids) // access `customerId`, `chargeId` here
});
```

---

Alternatively, if `Stripe` methods are also returned from `.then()` with `customer.id` , `charge.id`, you could pass `Stripe` method to a function that pushes both `Promise` values returned by `Stripe` methods and `customer.id`, `charge.id` to an array, where both `Promise` values returned from `Stripe` methods and individual `charge.id` and `customer.id` will be available at `.then()` chained to `customerTokens`.

```js
var arr = [
  [],
  []
];

var Stripe = function(val) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var d = Math.random() * 3000;
    setTimeout(function() {
      arr[0].push({
        StripeData: d // `Stripe` method data
      });
      if (val) {
        arr[1].push(val)
      }
      resolve(arr)
    }, d)
  })
}

var customerTokens = Promise.resolve()
.then(function() {
    // do stuff
    var customerId = 1;
    return Stripe({
      customerId: customerId
    }); // pass `customerId` here
})
.then(function(id) {

    // do stuff
    return Stripe() //
})
.then(function(id) {
    // do stuff
    var chargeId = 2;
    return Stripe({
      chargeId: chargeId
    }); // pass `customerId`
})
.catch(function(err) {

});

customerTokens
.then(function(data) {
    var ids = data[1];
    // access `customerId`, `chargeId` here at `data[1]`
    console.log("complete", data, JSON.stringify(ids))
});
```

---

You could also utilize `Promise.all()` , filter all results at single `.then()`

```js
var arr = [
  [],
  []
];

var Stripe = function(val) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var d = Math.random() * 3000;
    setTimeout(function() {
      arr[0].push({
        StripeData: d // `Stripe` method data
      });
      if (val) {
        arr[1].push(val)
      }
      resolve(arr)
    }, d)
  })
}

var customerTokens = Promise.all([Stripe({
      customerId: Math.random() * 10
    }), Stripe(), Stripe({
      chargeId: Math.random() * 5
    }).then(function(data) {
  // do stuff
  console.log(data);
  return data // return data
})])

.catch(function(err) {

});

customerTokens
.then(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(response, index) {
      response[1].forEach(function(ids) {
        console.log(ids) // filter `customerId`, `chargeId` 
      })
    })
});
```

Comment: but how would this work if your chain returns a promise?

Comment: @mido _"but how would this work if your chain returns a promise?"_ Not following?

Comment: you are returning values at each step of chain, how would you pass the `id` variable if you return promise?

Comment: @mido _"you are returning values at each step of chain, how would you pass the id variable if you return promise?"_ Return which `Promise` ? See comment at _"The second one doesn't have a return because of my sad attempt to store the result in a variable."_ . Though, if OP is actually returning `Stripe` method call to chained `.then()`, can `return` `Promise.all([Stripe.method(), customer.id])` with `customer.id` , `charge.id` included as parameters; filter results at `customerTokens.then()`

Answer (score 0):

the ugly yet simple solution would be to use (kinda) global variables:

```
var customerId;

Stripe.customers.create({...}).then(function(customer){
    customerId = customer.id;
    ...
```

a more elegant way would be to use context, and pass it as this attribute throught the promise chain:

```
function getExample() {
    var ctx = {};
    return promiseA(…)
    .then(function(resultA) {
        this.resultA = resultA;
        // some processing
        return promiseB(…);
    }.bind(ctx)).then(function(resultB) {
        // more processing
        return // something using both this.resultA and resultB
    }.bind(ctx));
}
```

read more details about this solution in [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250700/3074768)

best way to do this might be using [async promises](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/), but then you might have to wait till ES7:

```
var customer = await Stripe.customers.create({...});
```